# selecting a radio by clicking a div

Tags: jquery

I wish to be able to click on a div and have it select a radio button.  I have it working in webkit...but not FF.

The full example can be found here:

http://acgidev.acgisoftware.com/clicktest2.html#

```
<div class="aaEcmTemplateThumbWrapper">
     <div class="aaEcmTemplateTitle"><input type="radio" tabindex="4" class="aaEcmMsgRadio" value="EC_ORDER_CONFIRMATION" name="p_template_message_id">EC Order Confirmation
</div>
     <div class="aaEcmTemplateThumb"><a class="aaIframePopup" href="#"><span class="aaMagGlass"></span></a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="aaEcmTemplateThumbWrapper">
     <div class="aaEcmTemplateTitle"><input type="radio" tabindex="4" class="aaEcmMsgRadio" value="EC_ORDER_CONFIRMATION" name="p_template_message_id">EC Order Confirmation
</div>
     <div class="aaEcmTemplateThumb"><a class="aaIframePopup" href="#"><span class="aaMagGlass"></span></a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="aaEcmTemplateThumbWrapper">
 <div class="aaEcmTemplateTitle"><input type="radio" tabindex="4" class="aaEcmMsgRadio" value="EC_ORDER_CONFIRMATION" name="p_template_message_id">EC Order Confirmation
</div>
     <div class="aaEcmTemplateThumb"><a class="aaIframePopup" href="#"><span class="aaMagGlass"></span></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the jquery I am using is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //check on div click
$("div.aaEcmTemplateThumbWrapper").live("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:radio')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='radio']");

    if( checkbox.attr("checked") == "" ){
       checkbox.attr("checked","true");
    } else {
       checkbox.attr("checked","");
    }
    $("div.aaEcmTemplateThumbWrapper").click(function () {

        $('input:radio').attr('checked',false);

    });   
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `<label>`s?

Comment: Labels are the way to go and your code work find in FF (http://jsfiddle.net/kLL5E/)

Comment: Also, `attr()` for that purpose it's been replaced with `prop()` so you can do `checkbox.prop('checked','true')`. Also, this line `checkbox.attr("checked") == ""` makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys!!! It is working just fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must go with `<label>`s with `for` attribute:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" id="radio1"><label for="radio1">Radio 1</label>
<input type="radio" value="2" id="radio2"><label for="radio2">Radio 2</label>
<input type="radio" value="3" id="radio3"><label for="radio3">Radio 3</label>
```

Note that a `<label>`'s `for` attribute must match the `<input>`'s `id` attribute.

Comment: though this doesn't directly answer the question, I totally agree with the approach: one should always try to stick to semantics and web standards instead of reinventing the wheel every time...

Comment: I think the label will only allow me to click on the div around the actual radio input  -  correct?    I should have been more specific  -  I am trying to click on the div "aaEcmTemplateThumb" and have it select the radio.   Thanks Guys...sorry for not being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

```js
$('.content').click(function () {    
 $('.tlRadio').prop('checked', false);
    var val =  $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked')?false:true;
    $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', val);
 checkedValue = $(this).find('input:radio').val();
 console.log(checkedValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
   Div 1
    <input type="radio" class="tlRadio" id="radio1" value="test" />
</div>
<div class="content">
   Div 2
    <input type="radio" class="tlRadio" id="radio2" value="test2" />
</div>
<div class="content">
   Div 3
    <input type="radio" class="tlRadio" id="radio3" value="test3" />
</div>
<div class="content">
   Div 4
    <input type="radio" class="tlRadio" id="radio4" value="test4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: It was my first post so i don't have much idea about the flow. I will surely add details in future. Thanks